# Possible squares that a chess piece can move to

Tags: combinatorics

Fix four integers $a,b,c,d$ with $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(c,d)=1$ and with the condition that $abcd<0$ (this ensures that the two moves are of different sign slope).

Suppose then we have a chess piece that can make moves $(a,b)$, $(-a,-b)$, $(c,d)$, $(-c,-d)$. Place the piece on the bottom left square on an $m\times n$ chessboard. Given an arbitrary number of moves, what is the total number of unique squares the piece can visit?

Comment: You mean for *any* integer $k$, right?

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Comment: "chess" piece on a "chess" board

Comment: If $\gcd(a, b) = \gcd(c, d) = 1$, then that implies that there is no integer $k$ (except possibly $1$) such that $(a, b) = k(c, d)$. Otherwise $\gcd(a, b) \geq k$. It's enough to say $(a, b) \neq (c, d)$.